# How to add permissions to VisualVM launcher in idea?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, ioexception, visualvm

I can't run VisualVM from Intellij IDEA beacuase of below error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/VisualVM.app/Contents/Resources/visualvm/visualvm": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:451)
    at krasa.visualvm.VisualVMHelper.run(VisualVMHelper.java:150)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 48 more
```

How can I change permissions for Idea? I'm using macOS.

Comment: Please check that user who runs IDE has r/w permissions to the directory and the files.

Comment: It's my user and I've got permissions to r/w

Comment: Is it possible to run it manually from command line?

Comment: Same problem...